# Nvidia Cuda compilation - OpenCl error

Tags: compilation, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to compile stuff from Cuda SDK downloaded from Nvidia. When I type in "sudo make", everything goes well until suddenly I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open /usr/lib//libOpenCL.so: No such file or directory
```

and after that comes around 100 lines of errors like this one:

```
undefined reference to 'clGetProgramBuildInfo'
```

and at the end it says:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Gt 650M graphics. I already installed drivers, bumblebee and cuda toolkit 4.1, but this thing has been driving me nuts for the last couple of hours. Google giving nothing useful. Thanks for any help!

P.S. Their makefile looks like this:

```
 # GPU Computing SDK Version 4.1.15
all:  
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./shared
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./C
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./CUDALibraries
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./OpenCL

clean: 
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./shared clean
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./C clean
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./CUDALibraries clean
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./OpenCL clean

clobber:
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./shared clobber
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./C clobber
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./CUDALibraries clobber
    +@$(MAKE) -C ./OpenCL clobber
```

Comment: do you have a /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so on your machine?  This is where it gets installed by the GPU driver.  If you don't have it, then it may be a result of which driver you have installed for the GPU.  What driver did you use?

Comment: Yes. When I opened usr/lib, I typed in ls -a and libOpenCl.so was shown in RED colour! I have no idea what that means. And I have no idea why that error when it is in there

Comment: I don't see an NVIDIA toolkit for Ubuntu 12.04.  Which toolkit did you use?

Comment: also this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car) recommends running the sdk samples installer as a non-root user.  Plus there are comments in there for some makefile changes.  I assume since you mention bumblebee you have an optimus laptop.

Comment: the error that is being reported shows double slashes in the path which is why I think it's failing, but not sure why that is.

Comment: I downloaded toolkit from here: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-downloads i took ubuntu 11.04 version hoping it would work. But if I run it as a noon root, I get permission denied stuff and it exits immediately. it is an optimus laptop. samsung series 7 chronos with gt 650m and i7. how can i fix that slashes? what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: you should be able to install it as non-root if you install it to a directory that your ordinary user has access to.  What directory are you trying to install the SDK to?

Comment: I've put it in my /home/username directory and just typed in make. and it stops. unless i type in sudo make. if I type in make, it starts, and outputs this: /bin/sh: 1: cannot open CUDA_INSTALL_PATH: No such file
and then stops.

Comment: I'm not referring to the make.  I'm referring to the install of the SDK.  You may want to delete the SDK and any files and directories where it is installed and start over with the installer, running it as non-root, and installing to a directory like /home/username/cuda_sdk

Comment: im quite a newbie and don't really know much about linux and I'm sorry if i'm bothering you. how can i install it where i want? i don't even know where it installed this one then, if its not in the folder I run it from?

Comment: The SDK installer is what you downloaded from the NVIDIA web site.  It is an executable file.  When you run this file you are prompted for where to install the sdk.  Don't worry about deleting stuff for now.  As a non-root user, run the SDK installer (the file you downloaded) and when it asks you for an install path, give it a different path than what you used before.  Then run make from that new location as a non-root user.

Comment: I did just that now. I put cuda to /home/username/nvidia folder. I ran the executable without sudo. (I did chmod +x on it prior to running). But when I go to nvidia folder and type in make, this happens: /bin/sh: 1: cannot open CUDA_INSTALL_PATH: No such file
make: *** [obj/i386/release/bank_checker.cpp.o] Error 2
and it stops.

Comment: nope, 32 bit. is that needed?

Comment: 32 bit is fine, I assume you downloaded the 32bit version of the toolkit.  Do you need the OpenCL stuff?  If not, and the other portions are building correctly, you could try make -k   (in your original environment where you were getting the libOpenCL error).  It may build what you need.

Comment: i dont even know what it is for. :D this is becoming crazy. i compiled like that. it went through, but in the end said this: simpleGL.cpp: In function ‘bool runTest(int, char**)’:
simpleGL.cpp:569:13: warning: unused variable ‘devID’ [-Wunused-variable]
simpleGL.cpp: At global scope:
simpleGL.cpp:764:6: warning: unused parameter ‘value’ [-Wunused-parameter]
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/darx/Nvidia/C/src/simpleGL'
make[1]: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/darx/Nvidia/C'

Comment: So I tried running the deviceQuery from the C/bin/linux/release folder and it says: ./deviceQuery: error while loading shared libraries: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory . I'm gonna go nuts, really!

Comment: when  I run something else, it says cudaGetDeviceCount 'no CUDA-capable device is detected'. ah wll, ill install ubuntu 11.04 and try again tomorrow. i cant do it like this anymore.

Comment: This is a different issue. Your CUDA install (for whatever reason) probably did not create a symbolic link libcuda.so->libcuda.so.1. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12208936/749748.